# writing a function in bash profile, calling from terminal

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm new to linux and working in the terminal, and wrote a function to see if I'm on the company network or not

```
function isCompanyNetwork() {
  if [[ $(ipconfig getifaddr en0) == 3.* ]] || [[ $(ipconfig getifaddr en1) == 3.* ]] ;
 then
   echo yes
 else
   echo no
 fi
}
```

however, when i type the following in my terminal: `isCompanyNetwork`

I get:

`-bash: isCompanyNetwork: command not found`

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your terminal hasn't read the updated `.profile` yet. Depending on your setup and terminal, you might need to restart the application, or log in again.

Comment: @choroba Sourcing the file would probably be enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this function to your ~/.bashrc

I'm guessing you wrote this in a file?  If it's .bash_profile or .bashrc, you need to relog in or source the files (i.e. `. ~/.bash_profile`).  If you did this at the command line and haven't logged out, you can see your defined fuctions by typing `declare -F`.  Make sure isCompanyNetwork is there, or you did something wrong (created it in another window?).